# QGIS Linking multiple layers in polymorphic relationship

Tags: qgis, relates, forms

I am creating a tree survey system in QGIS. There will be three geometry layers (called 'Single Trees', 'Line of Trees & Hedges', 'Groups of Trees') and each of those layers has a 'TreeUUID' field that generates a UUID automatically.

I want to be able to link features on these layers to another layer ('stems') so that a feature one of the first 3 layers can potentially have multiple entries into 'stems'.

My attempt was to create a polymorphic relationship like this:
[image: Polymorphic attempt 1]

However I cannot then create the relation reference field on the 'stems' layer:
[image: stems form]

It looks to me like it should work. I can create a child feature on 'stems' from the main 3 layers but they do not link properly once created.
I am unsure exactly what I am missing and there seems to be relatively little information available about polymorphic relationships in QGIS. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: This could help : https://www.opengis.ch/2022/11/29/qgis-relations-their-widgets-and-the-plugins-of-them/

Comment: I had looked through that but there isn't really anything specific to polymorphic relationships. I am wondering if I just have to use a series of 1-n relations from my main layers to the 'stems' layer.

Comment: They use a polymorphic relation with the "Document Management System Widgets" as I have not used it I can't say if it will work with "non document feature"...

Comment: Facing the same behavior in QGIS 3.34.3.