# Managing PostGIS many-to-many relationships between several tables with different geometry types from QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, database-design, many-to-many

I have this data set stored in a PostGIS (16+3.4) database:

[image]

Each category of items being stored in its own table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.rock
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    geom geometry(MultiPolygon,4326),
    does_exist BOOLEAN default True,
    nickname TEXT,
    mineral TEXT,
    ....
);

CREATE TABLE public.pond
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    geom geometry(MultiPolygon,4326),
    does_exist BOOLEAN default True,
    common_name TEXT,
    surface INT,
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE public.bush
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    geom geometry(Point,4326),
    does_exist BOOLEAN default True,
    main_species TEXT,
    diameter INT,
    ...
);
```

Items in each category can be created at any time.

After some event, an item can be "destroyed"; its status `does_exist` changes to `False` but it must be kept in the database.

An event can destroy one or more item, of different categories.

In case of an event;

- a QGIS user must be able to create one or more **new** replacement item(s) (from one or more categories) as, let's say, a "substitute" for the item(s) destroyed.
- the user must be able to keep a link (in a many-to-many table) between items that no longer exist and those that substitute them.

##### What I've been thinking about:

If all geometries were of the same type, I would have created a generic parent table containing `id`, `category` and `geom` to which the three existing tables would have a foreign key. I would also have created a many-to-many table to store the relationships between destroyed items and replacement items.

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.parent
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    category TEXT NOT NULL,
    geom geometry(Point,4326), -- if `Point` were the unique geometry across categories
    CONSTRAINT category_chk
        CHECK (category IN ('bush', 'pond', 'rock'))
    ...
);

-- Adding `parent_id INT REFERENCES public.parent(id)` on each individual table...

CREATE TABLE public.replacement
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    replaced_id INT REFERENCES public.parent(id), -- destroyed item ref
    replacing_id INT REFERENCES public.parent(id) -- substitute item ref
    ...
);
```

But as the types of geometry differ, I cannot do that (well, I could, but I don't want to mix different geometries in the same column for technical reasons).

Therefore, such generic table would only contain `id` and `category` to which the individual tables can have a foreign key.

(I was also thinking of establishing the relation the other way: instead of a generic parent table, having a generic child table with FK to the tables of the individual categories (seen has parent tables in this case), but conceptually I don't think a FK can point to different parent tables.)

I was also thinking of using a globally unique identifier or keys based on two columns for referencing parent-child relations but I went into strange behavior in QGIS.

It may also be that I'm over-engineering the problem having my nose to the grindstone and that  a much simpler solution exists.

This is my current state inside QGIS:

[image]

But the relations in the `replacement` table (top right) are only showing ids from the `parent` table when editing or creating a new record, which does not help the user selecting the right feature. Also, the user cannot select more than one parent in a single operation.

##### PostGIS and QGIS related question:

How to design the database along with the QGIS project so that the user can create those relationships described above in case of an event?

Ideally, those replacing item(s) should show a label with the id(s) of the replaced item(s) and vice-versa:

[image]

##### Edit

I also tried the so called "[Polymorphic Relations](https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/joins_relations.html#polymorphic-relations)" but it's not possible to use a "Relation Reference" widget from the "replacement" child layer when referencing multiple parent layer. Even so the FK is defined using a composite key:

[image]

A mouse over the greyed drop-down opens a tooltip with:

> "The generated relations for a polymorphic relation cannot be used."

In that case, the `replacement` table was defined as:

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.layer
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    "name" TEXT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT name_chk
        CHECK (name IN ('bush', 'pond', 'rock'))
);

INSERT INTO public.layer("name") VALUES
  ('bush'),
  ('pond'),
  ('rock');

CREATE TABLE public.parent
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    layer_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES public.layer(id),
    feature_id INT NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (layer_id, feature_id)
);

CREATE TABLE public.replacement
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    replaced_layer INT NOT NULL,
    replaced_id INT NOT NULL,
    replacing_layer INT NOT NULL,
    replacing_id INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT replaced_layer_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (replaced_layer, replaced_id)
        REFERENCES public.parent (layer_id, feature_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT replacing_layer_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (replacing_layer, replacing_id)
        REFERENCES public.parent (layer_id, feature_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
```

and a child table such as:

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.bush
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    geom geometry(Point,4326),
    layer_id INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 REFERENCES public.layer(id),
    parent_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES public.parent(id),
    main_species TEXT,
    diameter INT,
    ...
);
```

###### Note to myself

QGIS Polymorphic Relations do not like coded DB values; the name of the referenced table/layer MUST be directly hard coded in the corresponding parent table! It should not be an FK INT. So that it can be chosen from the child/referencing layer in the Polymorphic Relation window.

---

##### Useful posts:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41941492/parent-child-design-to-easily-identify-child-type
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068033/postgresql-foreign-key-referencing-primary-keys-of-two-different-tables
[QGIS Linking multiple layers in polymorphic relationship](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/446499/qgis-linking-multiple-layers-in-polymorphic-relationship)

##### Version info:

QGIS version: 3.28 or more.
PostgreSQL 15 or more
PostGIS 3.4 or more

Comment: Why not just adding a `parent_id` field to the rock/pond/bush tables?

Comment: That's the idea I also had (see the SQL comment `Adding 'parent_id INT REFERENCES public.parent(id)' on each individual table...`). The problem is that the child tables hold the geometries. Therefore, from QGIS, you cannot add a feature "from the geometry-less parent"; you have to add a child but when doing so, the FK `parent_id` is not automatically filled.